# SQL Server SMO create Auto Numbering Index Column

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a project in C# where I create my tables in SQL server using the Server Management Objects for SQL Server in my program.

I need to create a column using SMO in C# where the primary key field is an autonumbering field.

Can someone tell me how that is accomplished using SMO in C#?

Tony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.column_members.aspx

Column has 3 properties: Identity, IdentityIncrement, IdentitySeed